# How to add two Fragments with RecyclerView in a single layout and Scroll them?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a layout with two fragments. Both fragments have a Recyclerview. I want, When I scroll any of a recyclerView Then another recyclerView also scrolled automatically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see each fragment at the same time, you could get the position of the viewable RecyclerView when you change views, then set the other RecyclerView to the same position.